# QML Multimedia play all mp3 in a folder

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qml, multimedia

I am trying to build a simple media player in QML . I can't use `QFile` Dialog as its a single window application running on EGLFS . I managed so far to build a simple file browser for QML and can play a mp3 from a fixed location. But here is where I am stuck:

1. How do I set the current selected file from the treeview as source for my audio ?
2. How can I get the `Audio` play each file with file ending mp3 from the selected folder?

Thanks for your help

.pro file

```
QT += qml quick multimedia widgets
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNING
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QFileSystemModel>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setOrganizationName("Power-Tune");
app.setOrganizationDomain("power-tune.org");
app.setApplicationName("PowerTune");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
//
QFileSystemModel model;
model.setRootPath("/");
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("my_model", &model);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));


return app.exec();

}
```

my main.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1 
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtMultimedia 5.8

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
    minimumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 480
    title: qsTr("PowerTune ")
    // visibility: "FullScreen"
    color: "black"
    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        property bool playing: false
        Audio {
            id: playMusic
            //source: currently selected file in TreeView 
        }
        Button {
            id: previous
            text: "previous"
            width: 100
            anchors.right: playpause.left
            //  onClicked: select previous item in current folder
        }
        Button {
            id: playpause
            text: "play/pause" //playing ? "Stop music" : "Start music"
            width: 100
            anchors.right: next.left
            onClicked: {
                if(playing == true) {
                    playMusic.stop()
                    playing = false
                } else {
                    playMusic.play()
                    playing = true
                }
            }
        }
        Button {
            id: next
            text: "next"
            width: 100
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
        TreeView {
            id:mp3selector
            width: parent.width/2
            height: parent.height
            TableViewColumn {
                title: "Name"
                role: "fileName"
                width: 300
            }
            model: my_model
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my code has actually a previous and next button. I just pasted the relevant portions of the code as previous and next don’t do anything at the moment. Corrected it just now

Comment: Hi , sorry i was driving to work . I made the code example now executable as stand alone . I would like to show only the files with extension *.mp3 in the Treeview and then set the source of playmusic to the current selected path with the selected file name

Comment: yes thats also a good idea.

Comment: It just needs to be able show folders and drives as i plan to use this on my raspberry pi and the music will 99% of the time be on a external USB stick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of notes:

```
property bool playing: false
```

Properties are better to be defined at top of hierarchy so that they accessible in all children, so prefer to put it directly in `ApplicationWindow` not in `Rectangle` element.

And, I think `TreeView` is not a suitable choice (Its a Quick Controls 1.0 element not available in Quick Controls 2.0 , and for mixing check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423981/qt-quick-controls-2-and-tableview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa));

You can do the model directly from QML, using a `ListView` with `FolderListModel`, you only need an additional of decorations for highlighting and selecting of files with mouse .. that's all, `TreeView` could be replaced with below code, it works and fancy!

```
...
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
...

    ListView {
        id: list
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        model: folderModel
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            // This will handle changing playlist with all possible selection methods
            playMusic.source = folderModel.get(currentIndex, "fileURL")
        }
        FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel
            folder: "file:///MP3/"
            showDirs: false
            nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
        }
        delegate: Component {
            Item {
                width: parent.width
                height: 40
                Column {
                    Text { text: fileName }
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        list.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: 'grey'
        }
        focus: true
    }
```

---

For your buttons `onClicked` just handle `currentIndex` of the `ListView` , for example in the *next* button add:

```
onClicked: list.currentIndex += 1
```

you also need to add some code to avoid getting index out of range or -1 ...etc.