# Qt Quick Controls 2 and QAbstractTableModel

Tags: qt, qml, qabstracttablemodel

I have a model based on [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) that I would like to use to display its content in a list in QML.

Actually, I need to display the first column only.

[TableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) does not exist in Qt Quick Controls 2 and suffers from performance issue and rendering issues on HiDPI devices.

There is suggestion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856015/1548052) to use a [ListView](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qml-qtquick-listview.html). But I fail to see how I can tell the model that I need to display the first column only.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: by default only the first list is displayed, maybe your model is particular, you can provide a [mcve]

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249521/is-it-possible-to-use-qabstracttablemodel-with-tableview-from-qtquick-controls?answertab=active#tab-top) , maybe useful ;) you'll find an example of `ListView`

Comment: thanks a lot. Indeed, ListView correctly display the first column of table model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is automatically done in QML by ListView: the first column from the model is taken for any requested role.